# Pushout in the Category $Set/J$

Tags: category-theory

Let $X \rightarrow J, Y \rightarrow J, Z \rightarrow J$ be objects in the over category $\mathbf{Set}/J$. Let, besides, $X \xleftarrow{f} Z \xrightarrow{g} Y$ be a diagram in $\mathbf{Set}/J$. What is the pushout of such a diagram? I know it exists because $\mathbf{Set}$ admits all pushouts, but I can't see explicitly what it is.

Comment: Generally, colimits in slice categories are computed the same as in the base category, and dually for limits in coslice categories.

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang is right, and this is a good formal exercise.  Prove this over any category:  it's no harder than doing it for sets.